# DocumentPicker.show() is not working with "react-native": "0.59.1"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker, uidocumentpickervc

I am getting this error in react native project:

> "undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_reactNativeDocumentPicker.DocumentPicker.show')".

Comment: I think you are not linking library.

Comment: I have linked the library even tried with reinstalling it. But since we have Upgraded the React Native version it is showing this Error.

Comment: Which version you are using now of react native?

Comment: We are using :
 "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.1",

Comment: Have you tried manual linking the library?

Comment: Please check this: https://aboutreact.com/file-picker-in-react-native/

Comment: Please check this [cannot-read-property-show-of-undefined-when-using-documentpicker-show-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71575875/cannot-read-property-show-of-undefined-when-using-documentpicker-show-in-react) I have solved my error in this way.